# opening fancybox from inside jquery .load content

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Hi ive loaded some content using the .load jquery function, in this content theres a fancybox image gallery but i cant get it to work from inside the loaded content ( it works fine by itself ).

any ideas ?

heres the code ive used for the fancybox

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
        $("a[rel=quest]").fancybox();   
    });
</script>
```

Regards 
Sam

Comment: you're missing a `{` after `.ready(function()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one instead

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel=quest]").fancybox();   
});
```

You're missing one bracked after `function()`

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize fancybox again for the newly loaded links.

Or you could use http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery as suggested here: http://code.google.com/p/fancybox/issues/detail?id=18

---

try this:

```
$("#choose_design_service").click(function(){ 
    $("#hiw-content-area").load("pages/hiw/what_we_need_from_you.html",function(){
        $(this).find('a[rel=quest1]').fancybox(); 
    });
    return false; 
});
```

Comment: How would i initialize the fancy box again ?

Comment: @user977397 after your ajax call .fancybox() again like this: `$('yourcontentdiv').load(url,data,function(){ $(this).find('a[rel=quest]').fancybox(); });`

Comment: Realy sorry to be a pain with this :                                ive added it into my javascript like this :                                          google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
 $("#choose_design_service").click(function(){
  $("#hiw-content-area").load("pages/hiw/what_we_need_from_you.html");
  $(this).find('a[rel=quest1]').fancybox();
  return false;
  });
 });                                                                 is the problem with the function i didnt include ? i couldnt see how to write it ?    - thanks for all the help so far by the way